# position problem when I animate an array of image with canvas and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I am doing a shooting game and animating seven enemies images.
[the image of the begining position](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AbdullA-Ababakre/BlogImage/master/enemyBegin.png)

And U can see that the distance between each other is quite well,just 10px.But after the animation finished ,the enemy image in the most left side got much farhter,which is higher than 10px.

I tried many ways and found out that the problem is in the update method.When I change the order of the loop
for(let i=0;i=0;i--) ,the most left side enemy image become much more further,the distance is higher than 10px.

```
    <canvas
      id="canvas"
      width="700"
      height="600"
      style="border: 1px solid #333"
    ></canvas>

    <script>
      let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
      let c = canvas.getContext("2d");
      c.fillRect(30, 470, 640, 100);

      let enemys = [];
      let limitObj = {
        enemyLimitDown: 470,
        enemyLimitLeft: 30,
        enemyLimitRight: 670,
        enemyLimitTop: 30
      };

      class Enemy {
        constructor(x) {
          (this.x = x),
            (this.y = 30),
            (this.width = 50),
            (this.height = 50),
            (this.xstep = 2),
            (this.ystep = 50),
            (this.direction = "right"),
            enemys.push(this);
        }

        draw(enemys) {
          for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            c.drawImage(
              imageEnemy,
              enemys[i].x,
              enemys[i].y,
              enemys[i].width,
              enemys[i].height
            );
          }
        }

        clear() {
          c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height - 130);
        }

        update(enemys) {
          for (let i = num-1; i >=0; i--) {
            if (enemys[i].direction == "right") {
              enemys[i].x += enemys[i].xstep;
              let max = 0;
              max = findMax();
              if (max == limitObj.enemyLimitRight - enemys[i].width) {
                for (let i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  enemys[i].y += this.ystep;
                  enemys[i].direction = "left";
                }
              }
            } else {
              enemys[i].x -= enemys[i].xstep;
              let min = findMin();
              if (min == limitObj.enemyLimitLeft) {
                for (let i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  enemys[i].y += this.ystep;
                  enemys[i].direction = "right";
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        animate(enemys) {
          this.update(enemys);
          this.clear();
          this.draw(enemys);

          let canRequest = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.animate(enemys);
          });

          for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (enemys[i].y + this.height >= limitObj.enemyLimitDown) {
              cancelAnimationFrame(canRequest);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function findMax() {
        let max = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
          if (max <= enemys[i].x) {
            max = enemys[i].x;
          }
        }
        return max;
      }

      function findMin() {
        let min = canvas.width + 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
          if (min >= enemys[i].x) {
            min = enemys[i].x;
          }
        }
        return min;
      }

      //  initialize enemy picture
      let imageEnemy = new Image();
      imageEnemy.src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AbdullA-Ababakre/BlogImage/master/enemy.png";

      function initEnemy(x) {
        imageEnemy.addEventListener("load", () => {
          c.drawImage(imageEnemy, x, 30, 50, 50);
        });
      }

      let enemyStart = 10;
      let enemyWidth = 50;
      let num = 7;
      for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        enemys[i] = new Enemy(enemyStart + i * enemyWidth + i * 10);
        initEnemy(enemyStart + i * enemyWidth + i * 10);
      }

       enemys[0].animate(enemys);
    </script>
```

wrong result which the last image is far away.
[the final effect of the code above](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AbdullA-Ababakre/BlogImage/master/wrongPosition.png)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Slack.

I've had a look at your code, and I want you to know it was not immediately obvious what the issue was.

Ultimately I believe I've discovered the source of the problem for you, and fixed it with only a minor tweak;

```
        [...]
          let max = 0;
          max = findMax();
          if (max == limitObj.enemyLimitRight - enemys[i].width) {
            for (let j = num - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
              enemys[j].y += this.ystep;
              enemys[j].direction = "left";
            }
          } else {
            enemys[i].x += enemys[i].xstep;
          }
        } else {
          let min = findMin();
          if (min == limitObj.enemyLimitLeft) {
            for (let j = num - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
              enemys[j].y += this.ystep;
              enemys[j].direction = "right";
            }
          } else {
            enemys[i].x -= enemys[i].xstep;
          }
        [...]
```

Notice how I've moved your `enemys[i].x -= enemys[i].xstep;` and `enemys[i].x += enemys[i].xstep;` lines into the else condition of your limit checks.

I believe your issue was that you'd been incrementing `enemy[i].x` even on rounds where you'd met your x limit and intended to increment y only, leading to a slight increase in X per iteration, but only for the last enemy; `enemy[6]`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: many thanks for your answer,it works. after then I got a conclusion that when we need to check and move ,we should do the check first ,this is the summary of my coding experience after I stuck in this bug for entirely 3 days.

Comment: @AbdullaAbabakre Don't stop now, you've still got the rest of a game to build :-D

Comment: hello Graham P health,I bothered a lot.I am sorry.Can you plz answer my new question about this project.[the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618281/cannot-partially-the-canvas)